# Memory leak when passing groupby in multithread pool

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pandas, threadpool, pandas-groupby

While i solved my problem by completely changing my algorithm, i'm still curious as to why my first approach had a memory leak, see below.

I want to process groups in a pandas dataframe. i use:

```
def function(template_df,group):
    for row in group.iterrows():
       ** edit template_df **
    return template_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=6) as pool:
            multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(function,(template_df,group)) for name,group in dataframe.groupby(['Col1'])]
            results_all = [res.get() for res in multiple_results]
            pool.close()
            pool.terminate()
            pool.join() 

for i in range(0,len(results_all)):
    meta_df= meta_df.add(results_all[i])

results_all =[]
multiple_results = []
```

The function returns a small dataframe edited by the data in each group. I then combine these small dataframes into one.

There are a lot of groups in the main dataframe, and yes, there are tens of thousands of those template dataframes saved, but they are only 150x150 elements big,and my system has 110 GB of RAM, so it should be fine.
In fact the `results_all` list isn't that big. setting it to zero does not release any memory, and neither does `multiple_results`.

I've checked all my variables with `sys.getsizeof` and none of them are growing outside of expectations, most are in fact not growing at all since they are dataframes of fixed size . Yet the memory footprint is only increasing. every million rows of the main dataframe i process, takes up 30GB of RAM, while i'm deleting the new template_df i'm creating.

What am i missing here?

**Solution**: I changed the function to output a list of indexes for me to recreate the template dataframes, so i could switch to a map function and just pass the groups as an iterable. This completely solved the memory leak.
So clearly it's a problem with passing/returning dataframes from Pool.
...

But can anyone tell me what the problem with the first approach was?

Comment: In `pandas` (and in Python in general) you may have a lot of variables assigned to the same data like, say, 10 variables assigned to different parts of the same dataframe. However, when you send variable to another process in python actual data is internally pickled/unpickled in memory (that is copied). I guess this may have significant impact on memory consumption.

Comment: @Poolka that's what i thought, but clearly those operations aren't being cleaned up properly, since memory usage does not go down after I've finished running the program and pool.close() etc.. is executed. that's my guess at least...